# How to implement JSplitPane in the BorderLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout, border, jsplitpane

HI,

how can i use the JSplitPane so that they show up in the borders of a BorderLayout???

So that i can resize each sise (NORTH, EAST, WEST, SOUTH, CENTER).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for that you don't really need `BorderLayout`. You can add the split panes together for that effect. Because `JSplitPane` only supports splitting of 2 components, you need 2 `JSplitPane` vertically, and 2 `JSplitPane` inside the second vertical `JSplitPane`.

```
JSplitPane horizontal1 = new JSplitPane(
    JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, yourCenterPanel, yourEastPanel);
JSplitPane horizontal2 = new JSplitPane(
    JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, yourWestPanel, horizontal1);
JSplitPane vertical1 = new JSplitPane(
    JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, horizontal2, yourSouthPanel);
JSplitPane vertical2 = new JSplitPane(
    JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, yourNorthPanel, vertical1);
whateverPlaceYouWant.add(vertical2);
```